# Create function in Postgresql that inserts data into the table row thats been updated

Tags: database, postgresql

I have been trying to figure out how to create a Trigger/Function that will calculate a value upon an update of a tables row. This is for a DVD Rental Database I am creating. I have some database experience but I have only started using Triggers and Functions. What I want to happen is that when an employee inserts a Movies return date it will take rented date and subtracted it form the return date and then multiply the days difference by $1.99 the cost to rent each day. I have the expression that calculates that. I want a trigger to run the expression and insert the result into that table.

For Example:

Customer returns movie, Employee enters return date into the Rent table, when this row is update a trigger will run an expression that calculates amount owe and insert the result into the Rent table row at column amount_owed.

Here is some things I've been trying, the trigger executes the function but i get an error afterward.

Function Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_cus_balance(integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

UPDATE rent
SET amount_owed=subquery.balance

FROM (SELECT date_part('day'::text, rent.return_date - rent.rent_date) *         2.99::double precision AS balance

from rent) AS subquery
WHERE rent.rent_id=rent_id;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION update_cus_balance(integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Trigger Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_balance
AFTER UPDATE
ON rent
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE amount_owed();
```

PGadmin III just say "An error has occurred" when I try to add a return_date and save the changes.

Comment: DVD rentals?  How quaint.  I do note that you are calling something called `amount_owed()` but defining something called `update_cus_balance()`.

Comment: What's the error? Probably calling a non-existing function?Also, are you sure that you want to insert a new row, not actually update the existing one?

Comment: I will update my post with the error I get. Both the functions and trigger inserted correctly. It's just when I update a row with a return date, I receive an error. Yes I believe I want to update a row not insert one. I'm unsure how to properly use my expression in an update query. We run a small DVD rental store out of our convenience store in a small town. So we still get a good bit of business. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: The column amount_owed is where I want the result of the expression to update at. the update_cus_balance is a function I created.

Comment: Okay I went to the log and found this error when I try to update a row. "stack depth limit exceeded".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jakub indicated you need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to make this work. Such a trigger has two important characteristics:

1. You have an `OLD` and a `NEW` variable which hold the values of the row before the update and what it will look like after the update. You can manipulate the `NEW` variable and those changes will then be saved to the table.
2. You can abort the entire update if some of the changes are not suitable.

For your situation, the trigger function would look somewhat like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_cus_balance(integer)
  RETURNS void trigger AS -- A trigger function should ALWAYS return trigger
$BODY$
BEGIN
  -- Calculate rent if the return date is set or changed
  IF NEW.return_date <> OLD.return_date THEN 
    IF NEW.return_date = NEW.rent_date THEN -- Same day returns
      NEW.amount_owed := 2.99;
    ELSE
      NEW.amount_owed := (NEW.return_date - NEW.rent_date) * 2.99;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  -- Trigger function should ALWAYS return NEW to succeed.
  -- Return NULL to make the update fail.
  RETURN NEW; 
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The trigger should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_balance
BEFORE UPDATE ON rent
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_cus_balance();
```

Note that I am assuming that `rent_date` and `return_date` are of type `date` (as their name implies). If they are `timestamp`s you could create two variables and `EXTRACT()` the date of rental and return into those.

Triggers and functions are not very complex in PostgreSQL, but do read the [excellent manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

An `update` on the `rent` table fires a `trigger`, a trigger updates the rent table. An update on the rent table fires a trigger, a trigger...

That's why you get a `stack depth limit exceeded` error.

It can be easily fixed adding

```
AND amount_owed<>subquery.balance
```

To the `WHERE` clause of the query in the trigger. However you will do much better changing the trigger to `BEFORE UPDATE`, for consistency it should even be `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger that checks if the `return_date` is filled.

It looks like a practice exercise so try the before trigger on your own.

Comment: Thank you, after adding that I tried to change my trigger to  `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE`. Now I'm not getting any error, but the `amount_owed` column is not updating to the expression. This is all for my families DVD rental store, I'm working on creating a database for them to use to rent out DVD's. Ive made most of all my queries and tables from researching around stack overflow and other tutorials around the web.

Comment: @Pugy365 Before triggers are different, you don't have date in the table yet so you have to use `NEW` to access a record. I'll try to update the answer if I find some time. But honestly I didn't know DVD rentals still exist.

Comment: Yep there are still some out there, we run it in a small town so we still get plenty of people that rent DVD's who don't have internet access out in the country. Thanks for your help, I will try to figure out before triggers.